# BigQuery streaming data from site javaScript

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery

I have a website and I want to send data (browser, page, etc.) into bigQuery.

How can I do this using only JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client Javascript library.

But the recommended way  is to sent first to your backend then use your favorite language to send via REST forward to BigQuery. This would be much much more easier as you can use directly a service account to authenticate to the API. On the frontend the hassle is the OAUTH and obtaining and managing keys.